# How to Stop the copy of ALL my pictures up to Dropbox

Tags: graphics, data-transfer, dropbox

I accidentally touched the picture icon (lower left corner) in my iPad.
It started to upload ALL 400+ pictures to Dropbox.
I DO NOT WANT the pictures uploaded. I can't stop the upload!
And it is taking forever. It keeps telling me that I need to run Dropbox to finish the upload process.

Comment: Just a few ideas: 1) check Dropbox config in Settings. 2) Disable Dropbox access to Photes in Security in Settings. 3) remove Dropbox and carefully read the options when you reinstall it. - report your results here in case it wasn't solved.

Comment: And try going to Dropbox on the web and temporarily, at least, deleting that device.